# How can I update the state by filtering the fetched data?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, fetch

hi guys  im trying to fetch data from my DB,
which looks like this:

```
inputData: {
  formID: '',
  inputArr: [],
  labelArr: []
}
```

but I want to put only a specific formID string inside the state, basically filter them, how can I do that?

this is my fetch code

```
componentWillMount() {
  fetch('/api/datas')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(datas =>
      this.setState(state => ({ inputDataArr: [state.inputDataArr, ...datas] }))
    );
}

state = {
  inputDataArr: []

};
```

and I want to shove only those with the formID of 3 for example , would appreciate the help!

Comment: First of all, there is no `arr` prop in your state, so `state.arr` is undefined. Do you mean there `[state.inputDataArr]`. Also, is `datas` an array including `inpudData` like objects?

Comment: oh yes sorry, it was meant to be state.inputDataArr and datas is including objects such as this: inputData: {
      formID: '',
      inputArr: [],
      labelArr: []
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `filter` the `datas` before updating your state. Here is a working example.

```js
const datas = [
  {
    formID: '3',
    inputArr: ["foo"],
    labelArr: ["foo"]
  },
  {
    formID: '4',
    inputArr: ["bar"],
    labelArr: ["bar"]
  },
  {
    formID: '3',
    inputArr: ["baz"],
    labelArr: ["baz"]
  },
];

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(datas), 1000));

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputDataArr: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then( datas => {
        const filterdDatas = datas.filter( data => data.formID === "3");
        this.setState( currentState => ({
          inputDataArr: [ ...currentState.inputDataArr, ...filterdDatas ]
        }))
      })
  }
  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return <div>Check the console.</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I'm mimicking the request here but you can apply the same logic in your last `.then` method. Also, use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated.

The crucial part is this:

```
const filterdDatas = datas.filter( data => data.formID === "3");
    this.setState( currentState => ({
        inputDataArr: [ ...currentState.inputDataArr, ...filterdDatas ]
    }));
```

We are filtering the related data then updating the state using the current one. Just, do not forget to spread the current `inputDataArr` here or you get a nested array of an array and other data besides that.